# Use AuthorizeAttribute without triggering a URL redirect on failure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Presently in ASP.NET Core MVC, when using ConfigureApplicationCookie and Authorize attributes, any failure will result in a redirect to the AccessDenied path.

This creates a challenge for error reporting as the end user is not able to see the URL that was originally requested. It also makes troubleshooting more difficult as a page refresh will only ever result in reloading the access denied page (without attempting to re-authorize.)

Is it possible to configure the middleware to return the access denied status code page without redirecting, similar to UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute?

Comment: Override authorize (override and overwrite some you should not do with .net because it is NOT open source)

Comment: ASP.NET Core (what we use) is open source. You'll need to explain more what you mean by overriding "Authorize" - it sounds like you're suggesting writing our own authorization middleware which is what I aim to avoid.

Comment: what i mean is yes override authentication process if you look at login method on account controller you see that it look at user if not authorize it will redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, 
        // set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email,
                           Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
    /* set if here if log in is not successful*/
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
       logger.log("stupid hacker");
    }
       if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                RememberMe = Input.RememberMe
            });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
as you can see in the lines when if method is fired and correct it redirect user to another page so what you want is redirect to current page that has already called authorization there you will get stackoverflow (wahahaha) there doing that will be wrong right? so what you do is put logger system in the if before redirect and you have every want to log and then redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution we ended up with is fairly kludgy, but it works so long as you're using Cookie auth middleware:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = async ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            var service = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IViewRenderService)) as IViewRenderService;
            await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(await service.RenderToStringAsync("Errors/Unauthorized", null), Encoding.ASCII);
        }
    };
});
```

The ViewRenderService is something like this (several examples can be found elsewhere):

```
public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(_httpContext, _httpContext.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using var sw = new StringWriter();
        var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, true);

        if (viewResult.View == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            actionContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewDictionary,
            new TempDataDictionary(_httpContext, _tempDataProvider),
            sw,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );

        await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```